# Tkinter Passing StringVar.get through command lambda gives initial value

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, optionmenu

Okay, so I am trying to make a menu system using Tkinter and am trying to save the string value of the drop down menu to a class variable. I have code to handle that part, but the problem comes with getting that string value to the function I have written. I know that it isn't my function that is the problem as I am using the print function for my example below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from enum import Enum

class CustomEnum(Enum):
    Option1 = 'Option1'
    Option2 = 'Option2'


class window():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.value = CustomEnum.Option1

        test = tk.StringVar()
        test.set(self.value.value)

        tk.OptionMenu(root, test, *[e.value for e in CustomEnum], command = lambda
            content = test.get() : print(content)).pack()

        tk.Button(root, text="Save",
            command =  lambda content = test.get() : print(content)).pack()


root = tk.Tk()
test = window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If you run this code, it'll constantly print "Option 1" despite what option you chose or if you add or remove elements (aside from removing Option 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line

```py
tk.Button(root, text="Save",
    command = lambda content = test.get() : print(content)).pack()
```

You are assigning `content` the value of `test.get()` which was at that instant (`Option1`) and it continues to be so unchanged.

Since you want the current value of `test.get()`, you would have to do this

```py
command = lambda: print(test.get())).pack()
```

Also, I believe you have misspelt `customEnum` instead of `CustomEnum`.

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple answer, by then again, I'm still learning tkinter